# Append html to webview content

Tags: html, objective-c, cocoa, webview

currently loading a URL like Google.com into my web view like so

```
[webView setMainFrameURL:@"http://google.com"];
```

How can I append html to that like "`<h1>End of page</h1>`"?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to manipulate the DOM (Document Object Model) after the page has loaded in the `WebView`. You can use the `WebFrameLoadDelegate` methods to determine when the page has loaded successfully.

To manipulate the DOM, you can [use Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/DOMObjCBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001206-BCIGCAIE) via the various DOM manipulation classes or you can use JavaScript.